# How can I modify files in a commit in a github action?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Hello I am building a github action in order to update the docker tag, in order to do this I have the following code:

```
git fetch --tags
serviceVersions=''
for serviceToRelease in ${SERVICES_RELEASE[@]};
  do
        latestRev=$(git tag --list --sort=-committerdate "*$serviceToRelease*" | head -n 1)
        version=$(echo $latestRev | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+).*/\1/p')
        newVersion=$(echo "${version%.*}.$((${version##*.}+1))")
        
        git tag $serviceToRelease-$newVersion
        git push origin --tags

        serviceLowerCase=$(echo $serviceToRelease | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')

        docker build -t $serviceLowerCase -f ./components/$serviceToRelease/Dockerfile ./components/$serviceToRelease
        docker tag $serviceLowerCase tag/repo:$serviceLowerCase-$newVersion
        docker push tag/repo:$serviceLowerCase-$newVersion
        
        serviceVersions="${serviceToRelease}-${newVersion} ${serviceVersions}"
  done
```

This only creates a tag but I need to modify files and add them to the commit with

```
grep -rli $version * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/$version/$newVersion/g'
```

In order to update the references to the tag inside the commit, I dont want make another commit because that trigger the action again, so I need modify the files and include in the same commit that trigger the github action.

How can I do this?

Comment: A commit with different files would necessarily be a different commit.

Comment: Just that, I am deploying kubeflow operators, and their have the version setted in a file, and I want to set the version in the file with a git push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  It is literally impossible to change anything about any existing commit.

You *can*, of course, make a *new and different commit* that's exactly like the original commit except for whatever you would like changed.  That's easy enough to do.  But it's a new and different commit and will have a different hash ID.  All repositories involved with these commits will need to connect to your repository, obtain the new commit, and switch to using the new commit.

> I am deploying kubeflow operators, and their have the version setted in a file, and I want to set the version in the file with a git push.

You can't do that either: it's too late.  The `git push` command pushes *existing commits*, but you need to make a *new commit* with this version-file in place.  *Then*, once the version file is in place, you can `git push` the resulting commit.  That's the way to go.

In other words, replace this:

```
git tag <name>
git push <repo> <refspec>
```

with this:

```
<update version file>
git add <version file>
git commit -m 'automatic update of version file'
git tag <name>
git push <repo> <refspec>
```

(with appropriate error checking and handling, of course).